# Changing GWT URL in development mode

Tags: url, gwt

I am currently using GWT and when i am lauching the server, i am getting the following adddress

http://127.0.0.1:8888/Jhy.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

but I want to use an address like

http://www.moribiz.com
because sometimes I will need to attach values to the url such as

www.moribiz.com?Username=asdasd

Is this possible??

Comment: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can. `?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997` means you run your app. in hosted mode. delete it and just run like that in web mode `http://127.0.0.1:8888/Jhy.html`

then it is normal web app. manage your godaddy account redirect to www.moribiz.com and apache and other things to your needs. and if you send the url you can get its value like that

```
    www.moribiz.com?Username=asdasd
    String value = Window.Location.getParameter("Username"); // asdasd
```

happy coding

Comment: ya this ok but I am working in development mode and i need to change this url because in development mode if i have to attach values to the url and use the get method to retrieve, how do i do

Comment: I am getting a confusion because in my url http://127.0.0.1:8888/Jhy.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997, I have this part ?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997

Comment: when i am deleting this part ?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 and running the url http://127.0.0.1:8888/Jhy.html, I am getting an alert message saying GWT module 'jhy' may need to be (re)compiled

Comment: it means you forget to compile the required module. please google it and look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975694/vaadin-gwt-error-module-xxx-may-need-to-be-recompiled/3547178#3547178

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile and deploy on a local tomcat. Then you can hit it without the ?gwt.code... part